# Matlab to Python translation of design matrix function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Last year I've written a code in Matlab for a design matrix in linear regression program. It works just fine. Now, I need to translate it to Python and run in Pycharm. I've been at it for days, and while I'm really new to Python, I can't find any mistakes in my translation, but I get an error while the code is run with the rest of the program.

Code in matlab:

```
function DesignMatrix = design_matrix( xTrain, M )
% This function calculates the Design Matrix for
% a M-th degree polynomial
% xTrain - training set Nx1
% M - polynomial degree 0,1,2,...

N = size(xTrain,1);
DesignMatrix = zeros(N,M+1); 
for i=1:M+1
  DesignMatrix(:,i)=xTrain.^(i-1)
end
end
```

and my translation in Python (np stands for numpy, which is imported):

```
def design_matrix(x_train,M):
    '''
    :param x_train: input vector Nx1
    :param M: polynomial degree 0,1,2,...
    :return: Design Matrix Nx(M+1) for M degree polynomial
    '''
    desm = np.zeros(shape =(len(x_train), M+1))
    for i in range(1, M+1):
        desm[:,i] = np.power(x_train, (i-1))
    return desm
    pass
```

The error points to this line: `desm[:,i] = np.power(x_train, (i-1))` and it's a value error. I tried using the online translator ompc but it seems to be outdated since it didn't work for me. Could anyone kindly explain to me if there're any obvious mistakes in my translation? I know it's a part of a bigger program, but what I'm asking is just the syntax translation itself. If it's correct, I'll try to find any other mistakes, though I didn't come up with any so far. Thank you.

**Edit:** Traceback

```
ERROR: test_design_matrix (test.TestDesignMatrix)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test.py", line 61, in test_design_matrix
    dm_computed = design_matrix(x_train, M)
  File "...\content.py", line 34, in design_matrix
    desm[:,i] = np.power(x_train, (i-1))
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,1) into shape (20)
```

I'm not able to change the test.py file, it's provided to me and can't be changed, so I'm only relying on the second error.

Excerpt from test.py of the function that gives the error:

```
def test_design_matrix(self):
    x_train = TEST_DATA['design_matrix']['x_train']
    M = TEST_DATA['design_matrix']['M']
    dm = TEST_DATA['design_matrix']['dm']
    dm_computed = design_matrix(x_train, M)
    max_diff = np.max(np.abs(dm - dm_computed))
    self.assertAlmostEqual(max_diff, 0, 8)
```

Comment: Can you add the traceback so we can see more details about the error?

Comment: Of course, just added.

Comment: Can you also add the code block for test_design_matrix so we can see how you are calling design_matrix?

Comment: It's up there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
def design_matrix(x_train,M):
    '''
    :param x_train: input vector Nx1
    :param M: polynomial degree 0,1,2,...
    :return: Design Matrix Nx(M+1) for M degree polynomial
    '''
    x_train = np.asarray(x_train)
    desm = np.zeros(shape =(len(x_train), M+1))
    for i in range(0, M+1):
        desm[:,i] = np.power(x_train, i).reshape(x_train.shape[0],)
    return desm
```

The error comes from incompatible Numpy array dimensions. desm[:,i] has the shape (n,), but the value you are trying to store to it has the shape (n,1), so you need to reshape it to (n,). Also, as GLR mentioned, Python indexing starts at 0 so you need to modify your indices, and function execution stops at the return line, so the pass line is not reached at all.

Comment: I tried it, and understand the changes, but I keep getting the same error as before :(

Comment: Hmm. So you're still getting ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,1) into shape (20)?

Comment: Yep, exactly this one.

Comment: Can you try desm[:,i] = np.power(x_train, i).reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1) ?

Comment: Alas, nothing changes. Still the same error with just the same values, (20, 1) and (20)

Comment: How about desm[:,i] = np.power(x_train, i).reshape(x_train.shape[0],) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137835/discussion-between-robert-valencia-and-lin-k).

Answer (score 0):

I see three mistakes:

- In Python, the indexing starts in zero.
- To power all the items of an array, it is possible to use the `**` operator.
- `pass` does nothing, as it is put after the `return` statement. The function never reaches this point.

I would try this one:

```
def design_matrix(x_train,M):
    '''
    :param x_train: input vector Nx1
    :param M: polynomial degree 0,1,2,...
    :return: Design Matrix Nx(M+1) for M degree polynomial
    '''
    desm = np.zeros(shape =(len(x_train), M+1))
    for i in range(0, M+1):
        desm[:,i] = x_train.squeeze() ** (i-1)
    return desm
```

Comment: I tried it, but get the same error as previously. I'll keep pass deleted and index at zero though for the next tries.

Comment: Try the edit please. The problem was that x_train was a matrix (it has two dimensions), and when yo do `desm[:, i]` you are accessing to an array. To get rid of the unnecessary dimension you can use `squeeze`.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work, I tried it but now it says it's a fail instead of an error, and I got this traceback:   File "...\test.py", line 63, in test_design_matrix  
      self.assertAlmostEqual(max_diff, 0, 8)
  AssertionError: 22357.537052901051 != 0 within 8 places. I guess it's a computation error?

Comment: This error is raised because `max_diff` is very different from zero. I would try to load `dm` (in `test.py`) in an interactive Python session and see what is happening out there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to python... are you saying that the problem would be in the test.py file in that function? I'm starting to think it might be the case.

Comment: Don't worry, you're welcome. The error is raised because the created matrix does not pass the test. It is not really a programming error.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to know that you can created orthogonal design matrices for polynomial regression using the *patsy* language and module.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from patsy import dmatrices, dmatrix, demo_data, Poly
>>> data = demo_data("a", "b", "x1", "x2", "y", "z column")
>>> dmatrix('C(x1, Poly)', data)
DesignMatrix with shape (8, 8)
Columns:
['Intercept', 'C(x1, Poly).Linear', 'C(x1, Poly).Quadratic', 'C(x1, Poly).Cubic', 'C(x1, Poly)^4', 'C(x1, Poly)^5', 'C(x1, Poly)^6', 'C(x1, Poly)^7']
Terms:
'Intercept' (column 0), 'C(x1, Poly)' (columns 1:8)
(to view full data, use np.asarray(this_obj))
>>> dm = dmatrix('C(x1, Poly)', data)
>>> np.asarray(dm)
array([[ 1.        ,  0.23145502, -0.23145502, -0.43082022, -0.12087344,
         0.36376642,  0.55391171,  0.35846409],
       [ 1.        , -0.23145502, -0.23145502,  0.43082022, -0.12087344,
        -0.36376642,  0.55391171, -0.35846409],
       [ 1.        ,  0.07715167, -0.38575837, -0.18463724,  0.36262033,
         0.32097037, -0.30772873, -0.59744015],
       [ 1.        ,  0.54006172,  0.54006172,  0.43082022,  0.28203804,
         0.14978617,  0.06154575,  0.01706972],
       [ 1.        ,  0.38575837,  0.07715167, -0.30772873, -0.52378493,
        -0.49215457, -0.30772873, -0.11948803],
       [ 1.        , -0.54006172,  0.54006172, -0.43082022,  0.28203804,
        -0.14978617,  0.06154575, -0.01706972],
       [ 1.        , -0.07715167, -0.38575837,  0.18463724,  0.36262033,
        -0.32097037, -0.30772873,  0.59744015],
       [ 1.        , -0.38575837,  0.07715167,  0.30772873, -0.52378493,
         0.49215457, -0.30772873,  0.11948803]])
```